# GetLegendGraphic with bbox or filter

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I have geoserver layer with sld style applied. The sld have like 50 rules using type attribute of the feature. Now i need to generate legend but only for specific area (i have bbox coordinates). I am doing this on server side and i can get all the features and their attributes of the choosen area (but i don't have access to style graphics ).

The only way i can think of implementing this is to generate sld style (rules) dynamically and pass it to geoserver as SLD_BODY. It seems a lot of work so I wonder maybe there is a better way of doing this?

Or maybe it is possible to pass some kind of parameter array to getLegendGraphic request like array of features ids or their type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a proposal ([here](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/GSIP-95)) that will implement this functionality. Feel free to offer any help you are able to.