# GetLegendGraphic and getLegendUrl function filter by extent

Tags: geoserver, sld, openlayers, getlegendgraphic

I tried to get a legend image from my GeoServer Instance filtered by extent (render only symbologies that are currently displayed on screen).

For this purpose I used the `getLegendUrl` function from OpenLayers 6 (docs here : https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_TileWMS-TileWMS.html#getLegendUrl)

So far I tried this example : https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-getlegendgraphic.html

But it does not work (even in this above example, any zoom to the map won't re-render the legend).

Now I tried this :

```
 var url = mylayer.getSource().getLegendUrl(mymap.getView().getResolution())
```

which gave me the good url with a `SCALE` parameter (which change every time I zoom in/out, because I had the listener on the `'change:resolution'` event).

The URL looks like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/MyStore/wms?&LAYERS=MyStore%3Ajunctions&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&LAYER=MyStore%3Ajunctions&SCALE=1789.2350833905004
```

URL-decoded :

```
base url : http://localhost:8080/geoserver/MyStore/wms

**Params**

    LAYERS=MyStore:junctions
    SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0
    REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic
    FORMAT=image/png
    LAYER=MyStore:junctions
    SCALE=1789.2350833905004  <=== THIS CHANGE ON ZOOM IN/OUT BUT HAS NO EFFECT : THE SAME LEGEND WILL BE RETURNED
```

Any ideas on how can I make the `SCALE` parameter (or anything else) modify the legend by extent?

Extra:

I found this old question : [GetLegendGraphic with bbox or filter](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61342/getlegendgraphic-with-bbox-or-filter). 
But it should be closed now because the link provided lead me to a 404 page...I did not found any questions on this specific issue anywhere else...

By the way here is my SLD (if it could somehow helps but I don't think that it has any effect here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<NamedLayer>
    <Name>Junctions Polygon</Name>
    <UserStyle>

        <Title>Junctions</Title>
        <Abstract>A sample style for junctions</Abstract>


        <FeatureTypeStyle>
            <Rule>
                <Name>710</Name>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>junctions</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>710</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <Title>710</Title>
                <Abstract>junctions 710</Abstract>

                <!-- like a linesymbolizer but with a fill too -->
                <PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <Fill>
                        <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFF33</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1</CssParameter>
                    </Fill>
                    <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                </PolygonSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
            <Rule>
                <Name>7730</Name>
                <ogc:Filter>
                    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>junctions</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>7730</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                </ogc:Filter>
                <Title>7730</Title>
                <Abstract>junctions730</Abstract>

                <!-- like a linesymbolizer but with a fill too -->
                <PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <Fill>
                        <CssParameter name="fill">#78D232</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1</CssParameter>
                    </Fill>
                    <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                </PolygonSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
            <Rule>
                <Name>Rule 1</Name>
                <Title>GreyFill BlackOutline</Title>
                <Abstract>Grey fill with a black outline 1 pixel in width</Abstract>

                <!-- like a linesymbolizer but with a fill too -->
                <PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <Fill>
                        <CssParameter name="fill">#AAAAAA</CssParameter>
                    </Fill>
                    <Stroke>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                        <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                    </Stroke>
                </PolygonSymbolizer>
            </Rule>

        </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
</NamedLayer>
```

Update:

Okay I found this question : [How to get the legends from geoserver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162034/how-to-get-the-legends-from-geoserver?rq=1)

It somehow gives me a way to do this but it's a very hard way I think: It supposed to first request features by extent on my own and reduce those features by the symbology field name, and send back a request of `getLegendUrl` with a RULE parameter to get only the specific rules...

I would like to know why the `SCALE` params does not work...

Comment: You would need to supply the required WMS options (see https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html#content-dependent-legends) in the OpenLayer getLegendUrl `params` option.

Comment: @Mike : you are really a good man ! How did i missed this (and I searched a lot !) ?! Okay i'll give this a shot and if this works please post it as an answer (last time i answered my own question even if the credit was for you...)

Comment: @Mike : it works as expected. Thank you sooooo much

Comment: You can answer your own question in an Answer, but when you answer it in the Question, it's likely to be closed as *unreproducible*.

Comment: @Vince : why closing as unreproducible ? Please take a look at my answer : I wrote it in a very generic way...everyone can reproduce it....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As specified in the docs of GeoServer :

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html#content-dependent-legends

> Content dependent evaluation is enabled via the following
>   LEGEND_OPTIONS parameters:
>
> **countMatched**: adds the number of features matching the particular rule
>   at the end of the rule label (requires visible labels to work).
>   Applicable only to vector layers.
>
> **hideEmptyRules**: hides rules that are not matching any feature.
>   Applicable only if countMatched is true.

Now the thingis that it also needs more params in the URL :

> In order to support it the GetLegendGraphic call needs the following
>   extra parameters:
>
> 1) BBOX
>
> 2) SRS or CRS (depending on the WMS version, SRS for 1.1.1 and CRS for
>   1.3.0)
>
> 3) SRCWIDTH and SRCHEIGHT, the size of the reference map (width and
>   height already have a different meaning in GetLegendGraphic)

Let's do this with the given exemple here

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-getlegendgraphic.html

It has this function :

```
var updateLegend = function(resolution) {
  var graphicUrl = wmsSource.getLegendUrl(resolution);
  var img = document.getElementById('legend');
  img.src = graphicUrl;
};
```

Now in order to make it works as a "Content dependent" legend I added those steps :

First create two useful functions :

```
var getExtent = function () {
  return map.getView().calculateExtent()
}
var getProjectionCode = function () {
  return map.getView().getProjection().getCode()
}
```

Create a the CRS parameter :

```
  const crs = `&CRS=${getProjectionCode()}`;
```

Create the BBOX parameter :

```
 const bbox = `&BBOX=${getExtent().join(',')}`
```

Create the SRCWIDTH and SRCHEIGHT parameters :

```
 //For this first we need to import getWidth and getHeight functions 
 import { getHeight, getWidth } from 'ol/extent'
 // Then Create the params
 const height = getHeight(getExtent())
 const width = getWidth(getExtent()
 const heightAndWidth = `&srcwidth=${height}&srcheight=${width)}`
```

Create the LEGEND_OPTIONS params :

```
      const legenOptions = "&legend_options=countMatched:true;fontAntiAliasing:true;hideEmptyRules:true;forceLabels:on"
```

Finally build the url :

```
 img.src = `${graphicUrl}${crs}${bbox}${heightAndWidth}${legenOptions}`;
```

Job done : it works.

Final code :

```
import { getHeight, getWidth } from 'ol/extent';

var getExtent = function () {
  return map.getView().calculateExtent()
}
var getProjectionCode = function () {
  return map.getView().getProjection().getCode()
}

var updateLegend = function(resolution) {
  var graphicUrl = wmsSource.getLegendUrl(resolution);

  const crs = `&CRS=${getProjectionCode()}`;
  const bbox = `&BBOX=${getExtent().join(',')}`
  const height = getHeight(getExtent())
  const width = getWidth(getExtent()
  const heightAndWidth = `&srcwidth=${height}&srcheight=${width}`
  const legenOptions = "&legend_options=countMatched:true;fontAntiAliasing:true;hideEmptyRules:true;forceLabels:on"

  var img = document.getElementById('legend');
  img.src = `${graphicUrl}${crs}${bbox}${heightAndWidth}${legenOptions}`;
};
```

Of course : this is only the part of the code (in order to make it works it needs the map object, Geoserver instance with a WMS or WFS to query. Also, each service must be bound to an SLD with specified rules.

Now a last improvment of this function, just for less coupling purpose, is to remove the resolution params and get it directly from the map object, like so :

```
var currentResolution = map.getView().getResolution()
```

now the signature of the `updateLegend` function is empty, and will work independently:

```
var updateLegend = function() {
    var currentResolution = map.getView().getResolution()
    var graphicUrl = wmsSource.getLegendUrl(currentResolution);

//... rest of the code
```

Some screenshots :

[image: Before zooming]

[image: After zooming]

Comment: LEGEND_OPTIONS hideEmptyRules is very useful and also works for drawing legends using CQL_FILTERS even if countMatched is not set. Thank you!